# Using a Userform for Database Lookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have Written a Piece of code that is supposed to Find a Value of a Userform Text box in the 22nd Column in my database. I figured that the best way to go about this would be to put together an if-then Statement, Stating that if this value is not found it presents a message box with an error message and if the value is found it Selects that entire row of data. the code runs fine without returning any error it just doesn't obey my criteria for the If then Statement and I was wondering if anyone could give me any ideas on how to fix this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim IDNUM As Variant



IDNUM = Worksheets("Petrobras").Columns(22).Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, , , , , , TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value).Value

If IDNUM = False Then
MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"

ElseIf IDNUM = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say database, do you mean an excel worksheet?

Comment: Yes my appologies when i refer to my database i mean an excel worksheet within the same workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Should look something like this:

```
Dim srch, f As Range

srch = TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value

'execute the find
Set f = Worksheets("Petrobras").Columns(22).Find( _
           what:=srch, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

'check for a match and select if found
If Not f Is Nothing Then f.EntireRow.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#return-value), `Find` returns a range if the search value exists, and `Nothing` if it does not. You're checking for a true/false value.

Sounds like you want this:

```
If IDNUM is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21).Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
End If
```

Comment: You have to change `IDNUM = Worksheets("Petrobras").Columns(22).Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, , , , , , TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value).Value` too.

Comment: Hi Josh i tried to use your code but it gives me Run time error "Object Required"